# angularjs accordion list anchor alternate elements

Tags: angularjs, accordion

I have an accordion list populated as follows:

```
<ion-list>
  <div ng-repeat="day in days"><br>
    <div class="item item-icon-left"  ng-click="toggleGroup(day)" ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(day)}">
      <i class="icon icon-accessory" ng-class="isGroupShown(day) ? 'ion-minus' : 'ion-plus'"></i>
      &nbsp;
      {{day.name}}
    </div>
    <a class="item item-icon-left item-accordion" ng-show="isGroupShown(day)" ng-repeat="exercise in day.exercises" type="item-text-wrap"
       href="#/tab/plan/{{exercise.id}}">
      {{exercise.name}}

      <!-- Trial LED -->

        <span style="float:right;"><i ng-show="{{exercise.watchedToday}}==true" class="ion-checkmark-round"></i></span>

    </a>
  </div>
</ion-list>
```

This populates list as follows:

[image]

Route which handles this is:

```
.state('tab.exercise', {
    url: '/plan/:exerciseId', 
    resolve: {
      authenticated: ['djangoAuth', function(djangoAuth){
        return djangoAuth.authenticationStatus();
      }],
    },
    views: {
      'tab-plan': {
        templateUrl: '/templates/video.html',
        controller: 'videoCtrl'
      }
    },
    cache: false
  })
```

However I have few other routes like:

```
 .state('tab.wordschatz', {
    url: '/plan/12', <= notice here (this can be 8/9/10/11/12)
    resolve: {
      authenticated: ['djangoAuth', function(djangoAuth){
        return djangoAuth.authenticationStatus();
      }],
    },
    views: {
      'tab-plan': {
        templateUrl: '/templates/wortschatz.html',
        controller: 'wortschatzCtrl',
        data: {
          css: '/css/wortschatz.css'
        }  
      }
    },
    cache: false
  })
```

I basically want to navigate to different pages on alternate accordion elements clicks. How can I have separate anchor links for alternate elements?

Comment: Can you explain a little better what you are trying to do. You could always wrap the elements and do ng-if but there might be a better way if I know more about your requirements.

Comment: @Shan I updated my question